# Are strings in app.config accessible to decompilers

Tags: visual-studio, security, app-config

An EXE is produced for a .NET C# desktop application: do decompilers like dotPeek, when examining that EXE, have access to the strings that were stored in the `AppSettings` section of the `app.config` file?

Comment: [`app.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/) is a plain text XML file next to the EXE, it does not get compiled into the EXE. If the program has hardcoded defaults (used, for example, if `app.config` is missing) then those are visible in the compiled code like everything else.

Comment: @dxiv:  Thanks for the clarification. I was under the mistaken impression that the app.config was baked into the exe. Does it get copied to the user's PC by the ClickOnce installation process, along with DLLs, when the publish setting is "Cannot be run locally"?  I cannot find it in AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

Comment: That is, when the publish setting is "No, available online only".   I assume then that the app.config stays at the publish location.

Comment: I am not too familiar with that, maybe [ClickOnce and application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-and-application-settings?view=vs-2019) can help.